# How to migrate data from a single row to an m-to-n-table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have an old table in a huge MySQL database with these columns:

```
player_data
- player_id (primary key)
- vote_chest_count (integer)
- premium_chest_count (integer)
- supreme_chest_count (integer)
```

(and a few other columns not related to my problem)

I want to copy these three chest columns from that table to this new one (manually, by using the SQL input of PHPMyAdmin):

```
player_chests
- player_id (integer)
- chest_id (integer)
- count (integer)
```

The three kind of chests are stored in another table "chests" and have the chest_id's 1-3.

What MySQL-Magic can I use for that?

best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO player_chests
SELECT player_id, {vote_chest_id}, vote_chest_count
FROM player_data
UNION
SELECT player_id, {premium_chest_id}, premium_chest_count
FROM player_data
UNION
SELECT player_id, {supreme_chest_id}, supreme_chest_count
FROM player_data
```

Replace the `{X_chest_id}` with actual integers from the corresponding table.

Also recommend making `player_id,chest_id` a joint primary key

Comment: Data is migrated now. Thank you very much. :)